# How do I get past this challenge in Fiz Brewery?

Tags: fiz

I have tried marianas quench with no success!! What is the watery beer??

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the list of beers in the [wiki](https://fiz.gamepedia.com/Recipe), I'm going to guess that the watery beer is Grubb's Lite (described as being watered down).